Counting matrix paths for (n,m>2) matrices
Given a $n\times m$ matrix with $k$ elements inside it, I need to calculate the number of arrangements of those $k$ elements that form at least 1 path from the top to bottom matrix row composed of the contained elements, with Moore neighborhood.
For $m=2$ matrices, I managed to calculate a closed-form expression that returns this number for all valid $n$ and $k$ parameters: $\frac{2^k n^{(k)}}{k!}$ Some of the intermediate formulas I used to build this result come from counting the total amount of arrangements with the $k$ elements and subtracting the number of ways to block a path, that is, arrangements without a path:
For $2 n-2$ elements: $\binom{2 n}{2 n-2}-n \binom{2 n-2}{0}$
For $2 n-3$ elements: $\binom{2 n}{2 n-3}-n \binom{2 n-2}{1}$
For $2 n-4$ elements: $\binom{2 n}{2 n-4}-n \binom{2 n-2}{2}+\binom{n}{2}$
For $2 n-5$ elements: $\binom{2 n}{2 n-5}-n \binom{2 n-2}{3}+\binom{2 n-4}{1} \binom{n}{2}$
After converting these expressions to polynomials with Wolfram´s FunctionExpand[], I can continue the pattern and build the final result $\frac{2^k n^{(k)}}{k!}$:
$2 \left(x^2-x\right),\frac{4}{3} \left(x^3-3 x^2+2 x\right),\frac{2}{3} \left(x^4-6 x^3+11 x^2-6 x\right),\frac{4}{15} \left(x^5-10 x^4+35 x^3-50 x^2+24 x\right),\frac{4}{45} \left(x^6-15 x^5+85 x^4-225 x^3+274 x^2-120 x\right)$
The problem comes when $m>2$, for example, when $m=3$ I only managed to count these cases:
$3 n-3$ elements: $\binom{3 n}{3 n-3}-n \binom{3 n-3}{0}$
$3 n-4$ elements: $\binom{3 n}{3 n-4}-n \binom{3 n-3}{1}-2 (n-1)$
$3 n-5$ elements: $\binom{3 n}{3 n-5}-n \binom{3 n-3}{2}-6 (n-1) (n-2)-2 (n-2)$
Resulting in the following polynomials:
$\frac{9}{2} \left(x^3-x^2\right),\frac{1}{8} \left(27 x^4-54 x^3+9 x^2+2 x+16\right),\frac{1}{40} \left(81 x^5-270 x^4+135 x^3+30 x^2+424 x-320\right)$
I haven't found any pattern for $m=3$ yet, since there are few valid cases. Thus, is there any way I can build an expression like the one shown in $m=2$ but for $m>2$ matrices?
